# json I/O IN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc

i insert Serialize data to SQL server For Example => Serialize :

```
"{\"Array\":\"Srvice\",\"Setting\":[{\"Id\":1},{\"Id\":2},{\"Id\":3},{\"Id\":4}]}"
```

above value exists in database .

Now , I read it with linq to EF IN ASP.NET MVC and my output is

```
"\"{\\\"Array\\\":\\\"Srvice\\\",\\\"Setting\\\":[{\\\"Id\\\":1},{\\\"Id\\\":2},{\\\"Id\\\":3},{\\\"Id\\\":4}]}\""
```

Why?

Comment: Did you stringify it ? It doesnt really matter if it looks like that , just parse it and use it as object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you insert it and how you read it?

It looks like you insert it without escaping and read [with escaping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

`\`  ->  `\\`

`"` -> `\"`

Comment: i read with this code :  var ObjSettingValueForServiceId = GeneralSettingService.SearchFor(s => s.SettingKey == "HomePageForService").Select(s => s.SettingValue);  and i get "\"{\\\"Array\\\":\\\"Srvice\\\",\\\"Setting\\\":[{\\\"Id\\\":1},{\\\"Id\\\":2},{\\\"Id\\\":3},{\\\"Id\\\":4}]}\""

Comment: @AminSaadati2 And write?

Comment: i add manual in sql : "{\"Array\":\"Srvice\",\"Setting\":[{\"Id\":1},{\"Id\":2},{\"Id\":3},{\"Id\":4}]}"

Comment: Is the difference?

Comment: @AminSaadati2 that's escaping. read link that i post in answer

Comment: Thank you . I understand it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx